# dividing two sets of points

Tags: classification

I have a series of points an a single real-valued axis. The points are either good or bad (encoded as 0 or 1). Generally zeros are bigger than ones. But they sometimes overlap. I need to a point which devised the two groups best. What techniques could I use? I thought about logistic regression, but do not know how do find the dividing number than.

Comment: Well, I think generally ones are larger than zeroes...

Comment: Thank you I was not sure about that (edited for clarity)

Comment: What is your loss function?

Comment: The difference to the division, squared difference would be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use logistic regression to find the cutpoint the following R-code should work:

```
df <- data.frame(x <- c(-5, -1, 3, 0, -4, 4,1,-1, 4, 2),
                 y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
fit <- glm(y ~ x, family="binomial", data=df)
# This gives you the cutpoint:
-fit$coefficients[1] / fit$coefficients[2]
## 0.4600296
```

If you don't use R, just calculate -Intercept / RegressionCoefficient.

Edit:

The code above gives you the cutpoint ($x$) that results in the corresponding logistic function being 0.5, that is, halfway between the two extremes 0 and 1. Say you got an intercept, $\beta_0$, and an regression coefficient, $\beta_1$. The logistic function is 0.5 when $\beta_0 + \beta_1x=0$ which gives $x=-\beta_0 / \beta_1$

[image: Logistic curve]

Comment: Could you please explain *why* this gives you a cutpoint and what optimality properties it has?  (This is related to @Stephan Kolassa's inquiry about the loss function.)

Comment: @whuber Added clarification! Regarding the optimality properties I don't know.

Comment: Actually this solution is not a regression but a classification. Even better.

Answer (score 1):

@Rasmus's answer in Python: (upvote him)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
y = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
x = [-5, -1, 3, 0, -4, 4,1,-1, 4, 2]
X = np.array([[1 for _ in range(len(x))], x])
result = sm.GLM(y, X.T, family=sm.families.Binomial() ).fit()
result.summary()
print -result.params[0]/result.params[1]
```

Comment: It is not at all apparent that this method minimizes the loss you cite in a comment to your original question, Davoud. For instance, if "squared difference" is interpreted to mean that a penalty equal to $(x_i-t)^2$ is assigned to each value $x_i$ that is misclassified with the threshold set to $t$, then $t=1$ is the optimal threshold, not $t=0.46$ (which is returned by your code).  What, then, is your *real* question: what exactly are you trying to achieve by your choice of discrimination threshold?

Comment: Yes, but the loss function it proposes is fine for my purposes.

Comment: OK--but it's not clear what its loss function is; what is clear is that it's not the same as the one you indicated in a comment.